# Ionic custom oauth2 redirect URL Angular

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0

I'm building an android app with **Ionic and cordova**. 
I have one wordpress website - where is oauth2 plugin installed with some access functions. I want first to get code and later send post to retrieve the token. I tested it in web-browser and it works well:

```
location.replace('https://xxx/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://192.168.0.129:8100/');
```

Im getting code after client login to my website and its redirecting to my app which is standing on ip 192.168.0.129:8100 with code in url - it wo. But in the android Im usining:

```
      var options = {
    clearcache: 'yes',
    toolbar: 'no'
  };

   $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('https://xxx/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://192.168.0.129:8100/', '_blank' ,  options)
        .then(function(event) {


        }).then(function(){


    });
```

Everything works but not redirection - it cant load my app again. I made some research and mostly people place http://localhost/ or http://localhost/callback to go back to android app but it also doesnt work for me. What is the redirect URL than?? How to get back to the app? 
of course 'xxx' are just for example;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have opened the url in the in app browser with `$cordovaInAppBrowser` , you need to listen to an event, `$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart` as described here, http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/.
So you can do it in the following way,

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('https://xxx/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://192.168.0.129:8100/', '_blank' ,  options);
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event) {
   // check event for which url loaded. if it loaded the http://192.168.0.129:8100/ with the access token, then handle it there and close the in app browser with, $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
})
```